# C - Improperly copied 2D array column

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an issue with my program.  The general idea of my code will be to use the FFTW3 library with circulant matrices.  They are generated from a random Toeplitz matrix.  Since FFT requires an input vector, I'm trying to obtain the first column from my circulant matrix, labeled aCirc.  This will be stored in a vector called aCol.  However, for some reason I can't properly copy the first column of aCirc into aCol.  The values copied into each position i for aCol are seemingly random.  This is the code.  The method used for copying the first column is getCol.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include </cm/shared/apps/fftw/open64/64/3.2.2/include/fftw3.h>
#include <time.h>

void printMatrix(int n, double x[][n]);
void genToeplitz(int n, double x[][n]);

void genCirculant(int n, double x[][n], double y[][(2*n)]);
void genVector(int n, double * y0, double * y1);

void getCol(int n, double x[][(2*n)], double * y);


int main(){
        int n;
        printf("Enter a value of n (power of 2): \n");
        scanf("%i", &n);

        double aToep[n][n];
        double aCirc[(2*n)][(2*n)];
        double xVect[n];
        double yVect[(2*n)];
        double result[(2*n)];

        srand(time(NULL));
        genToeplitz(n, aToep);
        genVector(n, xVect, yVect);

        printMatrix(n, aToep);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                printf("%i \n", xVect[i]);
        }

        printf("Converting to circulant matrix...\n");
        genCirculant(n, aToep, aCirc);

        printf("Retrieving first column of circulant.\n");

        double aCol[(2*n)];

        getCol((2*n), aCirc, aCol);

        printMatrix((2*n), aCirc);

        for(int j = 0; j < (2*n); j++){
                printf("%lf \n", aCol[j]);
        }

        printMatrix((2*n), aCirc);

        return(0);
}

//Extracts first column from circulant matrix
void getCol(int n, double x[][2*n], double * y){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                y[i] = x[i][0];
        }
}
```

As an example of how this is causing problems, here's a sample output.  I've provided 2 as the value for n.

```
0.172651 0.283250 
0.678243 0.172651 

10 
-1431519232 
Converting to circulant matrix...
Retrieving first column of circulant.

0.172651 0.283250 0.000000 0.678243 
0.678243 0.172651 0.283250 0.000000 
0.000000 0.678243 0.172651 0.283250 
0.283250 0.000000 0.678243 0.172651 

0.172651 
0.000000 
0.000000 
0.000000 

0.172651 0.283250 0.000000 0.678243 
0.678243 0.172651 0.283250 0.000000 
0.000000 0.678243 0.172651 0.283250 
0.283250 0.000000 0.678243 0.172651
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?  My program was working just fine up until the addition of getCol.  I've verified that aCirc gets properly passed to getCol by using printMatrix inside of it.

Comment: Can you narrow it down?

Comment: I got rid of everything in the comment that wasn't main, getCol, or the sample output.

Comment: Actually the issue has been resolved.  I needed to change the 2*n in the function declaration to n.

Comment: Just interested. If your n is read in at runtime, how can you declare double array[n]?

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue.  Trying to get my methods to accept 2D arrays was frustrating enough at the beginning.  The fact that all of this works now confuses me to no end.